# Continuous Training in Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am trying out **Amazon Sagemaker**, I haven't figured out how we can have Continuous training.

For example if i have a CSV file in s3 and I want to train each time the CSV file is updated.

I know we can go again to the notebook and re-run the whole notebook to make this happen.

But i am looking for an automated way, with some python scripts or using a lambda function with s3 events etc

Comment: I seriously don't understand why there is a downvote for this question. at least could have added a comment for down voting.

Comment: did you manage to get it working? I am having some difficulty doing the same.

Comment: yes @saed, I ended up using lambda functions along with boto3 sdk as suggested in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use boto3 sdk for python to start training on lambda then you need to trigger the lambda when csv is update.

> http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html

Example python code

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ex1-train-model-create-training-job.html

Addition: You dont need to use lambda you just start/cronjob the python script any kind of instance which has python and aws sdk in it.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple examples for how to accomplish this in the [aws-samples](https://github.com/aws-samples) GitHub.

The [serverless-sagemaker-orchestration](https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-sagemaker-orchestration) example sounds most similar to the use case you are describing. This example walks you through how to continuously train a SageMaker linear regression model for housing price predictions on new CSV data that is added daily to a S3 bucket using the built-in [LinearLearner](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/linear-learner.html) algorithm, orchestrated with [Amazon CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html), [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/), and [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/).

There is also the similar [aws-sagemaker-build](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-sagemaker-build) example but it might be more difficult to follow currently if you are looking for detailed instructions.

Hope this helps!